# conditional routing with global variables

Tags: angular

I am developing an angular application, This is the example [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x32any?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent2.ts).

As shown in the stackblitz I have created a global variable called isLoggedIn, and when user loggedin then I will change the value to true else false only, and I am able to get that value all over the application. But here my requirement is that I want to put a conditional routing.
In all the components I can able to get the `isLoggedIn` boolean variable, and I can check the conditions. Here my issue In `app-routing.module.ts` file How can I get that variable and check for the conditional routing.

If the user logged in then I want to route to `/home` page else redirect to '/login'. How can I check that value here.

```
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent}
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}
```

Or whenever user enters `/home` in the url, can we restrict at the component level using the `isLoggedIn` boolean variable?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent {
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use Guards?

Comment: No, just I am using with static credentials, if both are matched then I am routing to `/home`

Answer (score 1):

I think a Guard would work here. Something like this...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../services/auth.service';

@Injectable({

  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(public authSvc: AuthService, public router: Router) {}

  canActivate(): boolean {
    this.authSvc.isLogggedIn().then(loggedIn => {
      if (!loggedIn) {
        this.router.navigate(['unauthorised']);
        return false;
      }
    });
    return true;
  }

}
```

Then where you define your routes, include the guard in the routing object

```
  {path: 'login', canActivate: [AuthGuard], component: LoginComponent}
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent}
```

Hope it helps you out